# How to get Java's int.class in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I am using Scala to do some work with Java's reflection API. But I can't seem to figure out how to access in Scala what in Java would be: int.class, float.class, boolean.class.

Basically the classes objects that represent the primitive data types.

So what is the Scala version of int.class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

int.class, float.class, etc. do not exist. The equivalent boxed types each have a static field called `TYPE` which represents the primitive type. Is this what you mean?

e.g. for int/Integer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE

If so, you reference it from Scala just like you would in Java:

```
scala> Integer.TYPE
res0: java.lang.Class[java.lang.Integer] = int
```

Answer (score 14):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-20120430-094203-cfd037271e (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> classOf[Int]
res0: Class[Int] = int

scala> classOf[Integer]
res1: Class[Integer] = class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: This is a better answer because it provides the class of primitive types.